# Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Object of class Closure could not be converted to string in laravel,
i am trying get post by month and year

here is controller

```
public function getPostsByArchive($slug)
{
   $archiveposts = \Canvas\Post::whereDate('published_at', date('F-Y'),function ($query) use ($slug) {
                $query->where('published_at', date('F-Y'), $slug);
            })->published()->orderByDesc('published_at')->get();
      return view('posts.archive', compact('archiveposts'));
}
```

here is route

```
Route::get('archive/{slug}', 'PostController@getPostsByArchive')->name('posts.archive');
```

Comment: in which line you are getting the error? please specify the error.

Comment: there no error within the line, i am getting error in this whole function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `whereDate` wrongly, passing a closure as 3rd arg causes an error. Instead you may use [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-methods) and format your `published_at` column using MySQL's [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```php
$archiveposts = \Canvas\Post
        ::whereRaw("date_format(published_at, '%M-%Y') = ?", [$slug])
        ->published()
        ->orderByDesc('published_at')
        ->get();

return view('posts.archive', compact('archiveposts'));
```